# Find the 6-letter word hidden in the crossword

Tags: visual, cryptic-clues, crosswords

[image]

Every clue below is for a 4-letter word.
Put them to the crossword.
The words must be read inward (from outside to inside the star).
Some clues are cryptic, and some not.
A letter is put there as guide.
Find a final 6-letter word hidden in the crossword.

1. inverted mouse very far away
2. part of the shoes.
3. something you can see at a garden
4. every hobbit want to be ....
5. beloved back
6. something that you usually spin.
7. modify
8. move carefully
9. retreat loved animals
10. you need them to call each other
11. see
12. appear

Edited : I have made the crossword easier by giving the numbers to the clues.

Comment: These aren't really cryptic clues are they?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil yes it is a typo, I made it when I scramble the clues, sorry. The typ0 have been deleted. Only some of them is cryptic-clues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Image of the grid:

> [image]

Guesses:

1. inverted **mice** very far away

   > STAR (rats, backwards)
2. part of the shoes.

   > SOLE (a singular *part of the shoes*)
3. something you can see at a garden

   > TREE!
4. every hobbit want to be ....

   > TALL (do they?)
5. beloved back

   > this should be DEAR (back), but it doesn't fit!
6. something that you usually spin.

   > REEL (which just fell out of the other answers)
7. modify

   > EDIT
8. move carefully

   > EASE
9. retreat loved animals

   > STEP (PETS, retreating)
10. you need them to call each other

    > SIMS (not sure I see why I need them to call each other though; I'd just put them in neighbouring houses)
11. see

    > SPOT! SPOT RUN!
12. appear

    > SEEM

Hidden six-letter word:

> STRESS

Typo:

> the E and A get swapped in DEAR, backwards

Comment: For "you need them to call each other", I think it's referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module).

Comment: Thanks for the edit :o) I guess I should have made a picture.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note at first:

> The 12 answers will start from the 6 outside points, so there will be 6 pairs of answers sharing a starting letter.

And here are some of my guesses for answers (partial list)...

Something you usually spin

> Tale, yarn

Appear

> Seem

Inverted mice very far away

> Star ("rats" backwards)

Something you can see at a garden

> Rose

Part of the shoes

> Sole

See

> View, date